# Split values in cell by custom delimiter

Tags: excel, vba

I have have the following data in excel in one cell

```
Pankaj sharma;#234;#khushal verma;#786;#parul datta;#456;#
```

I would like to convert it to this using VBA:

```
pankaj sharma

khushal verma
```

Code from OP's comment:

```
Sub test1()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range

    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection.Range("F3")
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range(single cell) :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Arr = VBA.Split(InputRng.Range("A1").Value, ";#",-1,1) 
    OutRng.Resize(UBound(Arr) - LBound(Arr) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Arr) 

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? If you are asking assistance in coding, please post relevant codes.

Comment: Sub test1()

Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection.Range("F3")
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range(single cell) :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Arr = VBA.Split(InputRng.Range("A1").Value, ";#",-1,1)
OutRng.Resize(UBound(Arr) - LBound(Arr) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)

End Sub

Comment: @swapnil, edit your question and put into it the code you have tried. The comment isn't a right place for the code blocks.

Comment: @swapnil - I've added your code to the question. Excel uses VBA, not VBScript so I have adjusted the question tags as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two implementations, based on your code.

First one using `Split`:

```
Sub TestSplit()
    Dim Arr() As String
    Dim Res() As String
    Dim m As Long, i As Long
    Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
    Dim xTitleId As String
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection.Range("F3")
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range (single cell) :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Arr = VBA.Split(InputRng.Range("A1").Value, ";#", -1, 1)
    m = UBound(Arr) \ 2
    ReDim Preserve Res(m)
    For i = 0 To m
        Res(i) = Arr(i * 2)
    Next
    OutRng.Resize(UBound(Res) - LBound(Res) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Res)
End Sub
```

And second one with late bound `VBScript.RegExp`:

```
Sub TestRegExp()
    Dim oMatch As Object
    Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
    Dim xTitleId As String
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection.Range("F3")
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range (single cell) :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "([\s\S]*?);#\d{3,3};#"
        For Each oMatch In .Execute(InputRng.Range("A1").Value)
            OutRng.Cells(1, 1).Value = oMatch.SubMatches(0)
            Set OutRng = OutRng.Offset(1, 0)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: in above code instead of prompting for cell to select can we make a loop because now i have many rows and each row have one cell consisting of this type of data. so can we loop such that it will separate this values until it found any blank cell and it would be better that the result will go to another excel file using VB script

Answer (score 0):

[Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and [Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yscc53h0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), the standard VBScript tools for simple parsing/formatting, use separators, not delimiters. The difference: If ";#" is a separator, the line

```
"pankaj sharma;#234;#khushal verma;#786;#parul datta;#456;#"
```

contains 7 elements of which the last one is empty. Rule: n separators separate n + 1 elements. If ";#" is seen as a delimiter, there are 6 elements in the line. Rule: n delimiters delimit n elements.

Your data is structured - not just a list of elments, but a list of pairs (each consists of a name (?) and a number). That implies: the line should represent 3 pairs of elements and the ";#" must be a delimiter.

How to apply Split()/Join() to data with a delimiter format?

1. Split() using the delimiter as separator
2. Remove the spurious empty element at the tail
3. Join() using the delimiter as separator
4. Append the separator

In code:

```
>> s0 = "pankaj sharma;#234;#khushal verma;#786;#parul datta;#456;#"
>> a = Split(s0, ";#")
>> WScript.Echo ">" & Join(a, "|") & "<"
>> ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) - 1)
>> s1 = Join(a, ";#")
>> WScript.Echo s1
>> s1 = s1 & ";#"
>> WScript.Echo s1
>>
>pankaj sharma|234|khushal verma|786|parul datta|456|<
pankaj sharma;#234;#khushal verma;#786;#parul datta;#456
pankaj sharma;#234;#khushal verma;#786;#parul datta;#456;#
>> WScript.Echo CStr(s0 = s1)
>>
True
```

Alternatively, you could remove the trailing delimiter from the input string before the Split(). Even better: Use separators consequently from the beginning.

How to deal with the sub-structure of the data? If you have g groups of n sub-elements (e.g. 3 groups of pairs) use a n-stepped loop. In code:

```
>> For i = 0 To UBound(a) Step 2
>>     WScript.Echo a(i)
>>     WScript.Echo a(i + 1)
>>     WScript.Echo "----"
>> Next
>>
pankaj sharma
234
----
khushal verma
786
----
parul datta
456
----
>>
```

To access individual elements, compute the index like this: zero-based number of desired group * n + zero-based number of desired element. E.g. number element of khushal verma => 1 * 2 + 1 = 3:

```
>> WScript.Echo a(1 * 2 + 1)
>>
786
>>
```

Comment: thanks Ekkehard but problem is that the input is huge i have just given the chunk of input, can you help me with script which can use delimiter as ;#(any three digits);#

Comment: i have used following macros

Sub test1()

Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection.Range("F3")
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range(single cell) :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Arr = VBA.Split(InputRng.Range("A1").Value, ";#",-1,1)
OutRng.Resize(UBound(Arr) - LBound(Arr) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)

End Sub